# instance type (null) does not match any allowed primitive type (allowed: [\"string\"])

Tags: javascript, html, angular

"instance type (null) does not match any allowed primitive type (allowed: [\"string\"])

How to resolve this error when i save a form and one input field is sending null due to this i am facing this error

""/subscription/customPaymentTerms/name": "instance type (null) does not match any allowed primitive type (allowed: [\"string\"])""

This is the input field in some conditions it will be hidden, then it goes null how to stop sending it null

```
     <div class="col-md-4" [hidden]="!cpNetDays">
                        <label>Net Days</label>
                        <input
                          type="text"
                          (blur)="calculateAPR()"
                          [(ngModel)]="netDays"
                          class="form-control 
                          name="netDays1"
                          [pattern]="netDaysRegex"
                          [required]="payTermOptions == true && cpNetDays"

                      </div>

"customPaymentTerms": {
      "discount1Percent": "00",
      "discount1Days": 0,
      "discount2Percent": "00",
      "discount2Days": 0,
      "discount3Percent": "00",
      "discount3Days": 0,
      "dueDayOfMonth": 1,
      "dueMonthsForward": 1,
      "netDueDays": null,
      "type": "END_OF_MONTH",
      "status": "PENDING",
      "settlementFrequency": "",
      "settlementType": "",
      "variableFloatDays": false,
      "dailyRateAdder": "0.0",
      "maxFloatDays": false,
      "cutOffDate": 1
    },
```

Comment: Hey there. Can you add a default value to the HTML input Element in question? You can also do that by initializing `netDays` ( variable binded with above mentioned HTML input Element using `ngModel` ) with an initial value.

Comment: CAN you write here the code

Comment: when netDays1 is hidden it should send 0 or " " but not null

Comment: updated my question with json null value for netdays please provide solution with code thanks

Comment: Hey there. Apologies for responding so late. For better understanding of the issue you are facing I tried duplicating the issue, please check it in the following StackBlitz link, https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-iqxmse. Here, the input field `location` is hidden. On submitting the form, the value of this `location` field is transformed from `null` to ` `.